# How to print the output of two lines based on specific condition?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have the following file:

```
$ cat vehicles.lst


server.name.johnny

ford.mustang: 849448 found
gm.dennalie: 8548 found
Tesla.Y: 34343 found
################################
server.name.alex

ford.mustang: 849 found
gm.dennalie: 855698 found
Tesla.Y: 343 found
#######################
```

I am working on this file. i want to print the number of vehicles above a specific number and get the name of the server containing those numbers. It is better to get it resolved using one line command. Something like below will give me the number of vehicles using if condition, but how i can print the server name associated with that output. Please, help

```
cat vehicles.lst | awk '{ if($2 > 80000) print $0}'  
ford.mustang: 849448 found
gm.dennalie: 855698 found
```

I am expecting an output like this:

```
$cat vehicles.lst | awk '{ if($2 > 80000) print $0}' (need extra solution here to print the server name)

server.name.johnny
ford.mustang: 849448 found

server.name.alex
gm.dennalie: 855698 found
```

Comment: Awk is a programming language like any other. You can write code that looks for lines that contain nothing but `#`s and sets a flag, code that assigns the current line to a variable and clears that flag if it's set when the parsing of the line starts, code that prints whatever you stored in the variable described above _before_ printing `$0`, etc. Is there a specific part of the logic that's problematic?

Comment: (btw, as a general rule, don't use `cat foo | ...` -- letting whatever your `...` is do its own file I/O instead of forcing it to read through a FIFO allows for optimizations; for example, `wc -c` can just operate in constant time by seeking to the end of input and checking the current offset; `sort` can parallelize by having different threads read from different offsets in parallel and then merge-sorting their results; `tail` can jump to the end; bash's `read` builtin can read large blocks and then reset the file pointer instead of needing to read a character at a time; etc).

Comment: (I see you edited your input file format so `###` isn't present before the first line -- with that change you'd want to adjust the logic suggested in my very first comment to set the flag in the `BEGIN` block, and only set the variable and clear the flag on _non-empty_ lines with the flag set; or you could just treat an empty name variable as the indicator that the next non-empty line sets the name and avoid needing a flag altogether).

Comment: ...either way, the question remains: What's the _specific technical problem_ you need solved before you can write a working answer yourself? Is there a specific part of the awk language that needs to be clarified?

Comment: (btw, the "bash-completion" tag is only for questions about writing code to perform argument completion when you press the tab key; I'm not sure how it's relevant here).

Comment: Do you want the server name printed about every vehicle or only above the first vehicle from each `###` -separated block? Do you want the server name printed for every block or only a block in which at least 1 vehicle matched? Please [edit] your example to include a) a case where a second vehicle from a block is to be output and b) a block where no vehicles are to be output so we can see how you want those cases handled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cat vehicles.lst | awk '{ if($2 > 80000) print $0}'
```

GNU `AWK` can read files on its' own, so you do not `cat` here, you can do

```
awk '{ if($2 > 80000) print $0}' vehicles.lst
```

more concise way of filtering lines is just stating condition, that is

```
awk '$2 > 80000' vehicles.lst
```

where default action of `print`ing will be undertaken for lines where condition is met.

In order to know to which server given record belongs, it is sufficient to output server name, which might be done by creating logical OR condition

```
awk '/^server/ || $2 > 80000' vehicles.lst
```

which for `vehicles.lst` content being

```
server.name.johnny

ford.mustang: 849448 found
gm.dennalie: 8548 found
Tesla.Y: 34343 found
################################
server.name.alex

ford.mustang: 849 found
gm.dennalie: 855698 found
Tesla.Y: 343 found
```

gives output

```
server.name.johnny
ford.mustang: 849448 found
server.name.alex
gm.dennalie: 855698 found
```

Explanation: output lines if it starts with `server` or 2nd field value is above 80000. Observe that this will output *all* servers, even these which do not have any record where number is above 80000.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Answer (score 4):

An awk program consists of a series of condition/action pairs, where the action is performed only if the condition is true. (You can leave out the condition, in which case the default is always-true; or you can leave out the action, in which case the default is `print $0`; but in the case at hand it makes sense to fill out both for the entire program).

```
# Skip empty lines
/^[[:space:]]*$/ { next; }

# If a line contains only "#"s, clear the section name
/^[#]+[[:space:]]*$/ { name=""; next; }

# Whenever we have a non-skipped line and no section name, the contents of that
# line becomes the new section name.
name == "" { name=$0; next; }

# If we encounter a value of more than 80,000 and have a non-empty section name,
# print the section name on one line, then the data, then a blank line.
($2 > 80000) && name != "" { print name; print $0; print ""; }
```

With the above code, and your sample input, output is:

```
server.name.johnny
ford.mustang: 849448 found

server.name.alex
gm.dennalie: 855698 found
```

Comment: small suggestion - using `!NF` is a bit more concise and efficient than `/^[[:space:]]*$/` to identify empty lines.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of possibilities, using any awk:

```
$ awk '/^server/{s=$0} $2 > 80000{print s ORS $0 ORS}' vehicles.list
server.name.johnny
ford.mustang: 849448 found

server.name.alex
gm.dennalie: 855698 found
```

or:

```
$ awk 'NF == 1{s=$0} $2 > 80000{print s ORS $0 ORS}' vehicles.list
server.name.johnny
ford.mustang: 849448 found

server.name.alex
gm.dennalie: 855698 found
```

The above assumes that:

1. You want the server name printed above every vehicle that's output, not just the first one in a block, and
2. The server name should only be printed if at least 1 vehicle is found in its block.